# ContextProvider => Context APi : Children dynamically rendered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-context

I have a function component named: `Register`. I use [*MUI* (Material UI for ReactJS)](https://mui.com/).

Inside it, I call 2 components: `Step1` and `Step2`. Both use data collected through forms.

To simplify I don't post all the code.

```jsx
<RegisterContextProvider>
    {activeStep + 1 === 1 && (<Step1 handleNext={handleNext} />)}
    {activeStep + 1 === 2 && (<Step2 handleNext={handleNext} handleBack={handleBack} />)}
</RegisterContextProvider>
```

When I click the "Next button" inside `Step1`, I go the next step of the *MUI* STEPPER component and render: `Step2`.

`Step2` is rendered in the list of children of `RegisterContextProvider`, and `Step1` disappears from the list, and then the data stored in the `Step1` form is reinitialized.

Is there a way to wrap the components inside a higher level, like this:

```jsx
<RegisterContextProvider>
    <Register/>
</RegisterContextProvider>
```

Thank You for advice

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Register` component that will receive an array of objects with the data of the step components and the index of the current step.

Example:

```jsx
import React, {useMemo} from 'react';

const outOfBoundsOfStepsData = {
    Component: () => (<span>Index out of bounds of array</span>),
    props: {}
};

const Register = ({steps, index}) => {
    const {Component: Step, props} = useMemo(() => steps[index] || outOfBoundsOfStepsData, [steps, index]);

    return <Step {...props} />;
};

const Step1 = () => {
    // TODO
};

const Step2 = () => {
    // TODO
};

const App = () => {
    const steps = [
        {
            Component: Step1,
            props: {
                handleNext: () => console.log('TODO handleNext')
            }
        },
        {
            Component: Step2,
            props: {
                handleNext: () => console.log('TODO handleNext'),
                handleBack: () => console.log('TODO handleBack')
            }
        }
    ];

    const index = 0; // TODO

    return (
        <RegisterContextProvider>
            <Register steps={steps} index={index}/>
        </RegisterContextProvider>
    );
};
```